# Randomize the arrangement of DIVs on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this structure of DIVs:

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p style="font-family:SimHei;font-size: 25px;"><?php echo $word[$i]; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Correct</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p><?php echo $pinyin[$i]; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Incorrect</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p><?php echo $meaning[$i]; ?></p>
        </div>
         <div class="Cell">
            <p>Result</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My PHP code will generate the DIVs based on the total number of input I have, but I want the "Table" div to be displayed in a random position each time, because there's about 150 in total and I don't want the order to be the same on page load. How to achieve that with jQuery?

Comment: You want to shuffle the `.Row`? What have you done so far?

Comment: Not .Row. I will have about 150 of this structure by the time the page loads. I just want the order of .Table DIVs to be random on display

Comment: This is such an easy question to google... Since you are sorting a list of  `.Table` elements, it's content and therefore your code example is irrelevant. See https://codepen.io/MillerTime/pen/grZOBo

Comment: I used this and it worked very quickly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is such an easy question to google... Since you are sorting a
>   list of .Table elements, it's content and therefore your code example
>   is irrelevant. See codepen.io/MillerTime/pen/grZOBo

This was the solution I used, suggested by Pablo as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could create array of indexes, randomize order of that array and then use `sort` function to create new html with randomized elements.

```js
const divs = $(".Table");
const parent = divs.parent();

// create array of indexes
const order = Array.from(Array(divs.length), (_, i) => i);

// randomize index order
order.forEach((e, i) => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length);
  order[i] = order[random];
  order[random] = e;
})

// sort by randomized order
const sorted = divs.sort((a, b) => {
  return order.indexOf($(a).index()) - order.indexOf($(b).index())
})

// update html 
parent.html(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="Table">1</div>
  <div class="Table">2</div>
  <div class="Table">3</div>
  <div class="Table">4</div>
  <div class="Table">5</div>
  <div class="Table">6</div>
</div>
```